# $PATH variable on Mac OS 10.6 Server keeps resetting back

Tags: macos, path, operating-system

In a terminal window I run:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin>> ~/.bash_profile

Then when I echo $PATH the new path shows alright.

But if I close that window, open another window, the path disappears!

How to change the PATH variable?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The command you have will set the path and then put the output from that command at the end of your .bash_profile.

You want to put the command itself into the .bash_profile.

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

It won't take effect until you start a new terminal session.

Comment: Ack, no!  Use single-quotes around the export command, not double-quotes. With double-quotes, it permanently embeds your current $PATH into the .bash_profile -- which will work fine for the moment, but may cause weird and incomprehensible problems later.  If you've already done this, you should edit your .bash_profile (it's just a text file) and correct the last line to read `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to start a new Terminal session in order to apply the changes to the
~/.bash_profile.

Just type in the Terminal

```
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to save the

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

in the .bash_profile, as you're trying. However, the export statement is not just displayed text, so appending it won't work. Use an editor to do it.